# I forgot my localhost root password

Tags: ssh, password, password-recovery, hadoop

I installed Hadoop on my machine.
To start it, I was logging in as the user named `hduser`.

I connected to the ssh port using `ssh localhost` command.

Then I went to the `bin` folder of hadoop to start the `namenode(sh start-all.sh)` hduser's password was asked which I entered.

Now it entered a new prompt - `root@localhost`.
It asked for a password which I think I have forgotten.
Is it asking for the `ssh public key` password? If yes then how do I use it to log in. Of not how do I set my root password?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 1):

setup a root password using,

```
sudo passwd
```

below URL gives you more detail about user management. https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/user-management.html

Comment: Thank you Prashant. The root password was already set. I want to reset it.